# Несколько столбцов в JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Опять я с глупыми вопросами...

Как, например, в Акцессе: есть комбобокс, у него есть свой источник данных, например, селект по двум полям: наименование и идентификатор. Наименование отображается, идентификатор нет, но при выборе значения, он (`id`) сохраняется в некое поле, делая таким образом `fk`.

Как подобное реализовать в JAVA на `JComboBox`? Я, честно говоря, не нашел, чтобы через `DefaultComboBoxModel` можно было передать в комбобокс два столба...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если класть туда объекты, то отображаться будет то, что возвращает toString(), но получить из него можно сам объект через метод [getSelectedItem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

Comment: спасибо, покопаю в эту сторону